# unable to match format of file using regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on a regex to match format of a sample Hl7 message given below:

```
MSH|^~\`|674|GHC|SISRL|PAML|20060922162830|L674-200609221628310220|ORU^R01|ORU000016168|P|2.3|||AL|AL
PID|1|000-0000|||””|1922974|151-76-5760|||||||||||N
PV1|1|2|||||||| ||||||N|| ||
ORC|RE||2060059||||^^^200707061707^^ ||200707051013|DIONA |||””|||1007
OBR|||2060059|999991^Knee MRI WO| |200707061707|200707061621|200707061707||||””|””|||
OBX|1|TX|||PROCEDURE: MRI OF THE LEFT KNEE WITHOUT CONTRAST||||||F
```

$filecontents hold the above message.

```
$filecontents=~/^(.*?\rOBX\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|)(.*?)(.*?)/;
$begin=$1;
$end=$3;
$content=$2;
```

The desired outcome of the 3 variables should be as follows :

```
$begin = "MSH|^~\`|674|GHC|SISRL|PAML|20060922162830|L674-200609221628310220|ORU^R01|ORU000016168|P|2.3|||AL |AL
PID|1|000-0000|||””|1922974|151-76-5760|||||||||||N
PV1|1|2|||||||| ||||||N|| ||
ORC|RE||2060059||||^^^200707061707^^ ||200707051013|DIONA |||””|||1007
OBR|||2060059|999991^Knee MRI WO| |200707061707|200707061621|200707061707||||””|””|||
OBX|1|TX|||";

$end = "||||||F";

$content = "PROCEDURE: MRI OF THE LEFT KNEE WITHOUT CONTRAST";
```

But I am not the output. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it was just missing the $.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
$data =~ /(.*?^OBX\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|)(.*?)\|(.*?)$/ms;

my ($begin, $content, $end) = ($1, $2, $3);

print "BEGIN: $begin\n";
print "CONTENT: $content\n";
print "END: $end\n";

__DATA__
MSH|^~\`|674|GHC|SISRL|PAML|20060922162830|L674-200609221628310220|ORU^R01|ORU000016168|P|2.3|||AL|AL
PID|1|000-0000|||""|1922974|151-76-5760|||||||||||N
PV1|1|2|||||||| ||||||N|| ||
ORC|RE||2060059||||^^^200707061707^^ ||200707051013|DIONA |||""|||1007
OBR|||2060059|999991^Knee MRI WO| |200707061707|200707061621|200707061707||||""|""|||
OBX|1|TX|||PROCEDURE: MRI OF THE LEFT KNEE WITHOUT CONTRAST||||||F
```

Output

```
BEGIN: MSH|^~\`|674|GHC|SISRL|PAML|20060922162830|L674-200609221628310220|ORU^R01|ORU000016168|P|2.3|||AL|AL
PID|1|000-0000|||""|1922974|151-76-5760|||||||||||N
PV1|1|2|||||||| ||||||N|| ||
ORC|RE||2060059||||^^^200707061707^^ ||200707051013|DIONA |||""|||1007
OBR|||2060059|999991^Knee MRI WO| |200707061707|200707061621|200707061707||||""|""|||
OBX|1|TX|||
CONTENT: PROCEDURE: MRI OF THE LEFT KNEE WITHOUT CONTRAST
END: |||||F
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
$filecontents =~ /(.*?^OBX\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|)(.*?)\|(.*?)/ms;
```

The key changes are:

1. Using the `/s` modifier so that the any character `.` will match newlines.
2. Changing `\r` to be `^` with the addition of the `/m` modifier.
3. Adding a delimiter between your 2nd and 3rd capture groups.

In a full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ /(.*?^OBX\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|)(.*?)\|(.*?)/ms;

my ($begin, $content, $end) = ($1, $2, $3);

print "$content\n";

__DATA__
MSH|^~\`|674|GHC|SISRL|PAML|20060922162830|L674-200609221628310220|ORU^R01|ORU000016168|P|2.3|||AL|AL
PID|1|000-0000|||””|1922974|151-76-5760|||||||||||N
PV1|1|2|||||||| ||||||N|| ||
ORC|RE||2060059||||^^^200707061707^^ ||200707051013|DIONA |||””|||1007
OBR|||2060059|999991^Knee MRI WO| |200707061707|200707061621|200707061707||||””|””|||
OBX|1|TX|||PROCEDURE: MRI OF THE LEFT KNEE WITHOUT CONTRAST||||||F
```

Outputs:

```
PROCEDURE: MRI OF THE LEFT KNEE WITHOUT CONTRAST
```